# How to query Firebase for keys that match a string prefix

Tags: firebase

Since firebase not support any spatial indexing then I use geohash which someone advice here.
Geohash is using characters to find the nearby.

So let say I have `w22qt4vhye1c` `w99qt4vdf4vc` `w22qt4vhzerct` geohash store in firebase and I want to query only which geohash close to `w22qt4`.

How to do that?

I know firebase has startAt. I tried but not work.

**UPDATE**

Storing geohash to firebase

```
//Encode lat lng, result w22qt4vhye1c3
var geoHashLatLng = encodeGeoHash(lat,lng);
firebaseRef.child('/geohash/' + geoHashLatLng).set(id);
```

so in json

```
  root
   - geohash
      - w22qt4vhye1c3
         - id
      - z99qt4vdf4vc
      - w22qt4vhzerct
```

My question here.
I Just want to query geohash which start from characters `w22qt4`. Can we do that in firebase?

**UPDATE 2**
`startAt()` seems like not query with characters start with ...

Example: I have following gehash

geohash node

```
geohash
  - a123
  - a333
  - b123
  - c123
  - d123
```

With the following code

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase('https://test.firebaseio.com');
var query = firebaseRef.child('/geohash').startAt(null, 'a');
query.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.name());
});
```

Will get this results

```
startAt(null, 'a') //return a123, a333, b123, c123, d123
startAt(null, 'c123') //return c123, d123
startAt(null, 'd') //return d123
```

My expected results

```
startAt(null, 'a') //return a123, a333
startAt(null, 'c123') //return c123
startAt(null, 'd') //return d123
```

My guess, startAt() will query the 26 alphabet letters in sequence but not matching. 
So, what can I do in firebase so I can get my expected results above?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of what you're trying so I can provide more meaningful feedback?

Comment: @AndrewLee  Hi, I just updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: You can use "endAt" to end at a particular key. See the edits to my post below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to Andrew's answer above, what you want to do to get the desired effect with geohashes (i.e. be able to do prefix queries that let you specify accuracy in the 'query', specifically, for example every 3 characters in the geohash gets you ~ +-80km) is to store the data in a more granular and discretized manner.

So, rather than how you're storing it now, you'll want to save the data by chopping the geohash string key into fragments (I've done it at the 3 character boundary, but you should choose an appropriate tokenization strategy that gives you the desired accuracy) and use each fragment as a child name, as such:

```
root
  - geohash
      - w22
        - qt4
          - vhy
            - e1c
              - w22qt4vhye1c3
                - id
          - vhz
            - erc
              - w22qt4vhzerct
                - id
      - z99
          - qt4
            - vdf
              - z99qt4vdf4vc
                - id
```

Then, as in your question, when you need to get all geohashes that start with `w22qt4` you would do a query against:

```
firebaseRef.child('/geohash/w22/qt4/')
```

Which would then give you the `vhy` and `vhz` children which then have all the actual geohashes that you were interested in.

Comment: How to I query where the val under sub-child? I read to firebase docs. I found `hasChildren()` and `forEach()`. Is that the right things to use?  By the way, can I use in angularFire?  because i'm using firebase with angularjs.

Comment: Since the data has been denormalized in the given manner, you wouldn't need to apply Firebase queries. You can attach listeners to the appropriate level in the tree and it will return all sub children in the snapshots being returned.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a normal startAt query to find keys near the specified key. For example, in this case you'd:

```
var query = firebaseRef.child("geohash").startAt(null, 'c').limit(5);
query.on("child_added", ...);
```

This will give you the 5 elements after geoHashLatLng when sorted lexigraphically.

If you want to end your query at some specified key, you can do that as well. For example:

```
var query = firebaseRef.child("geohash").startAt(null, 'c').endAt('d');
```

Comment: This doesn't get what I want,  I updated my question again. I think more clear this time. Please check it out. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I don't know what the ending is. 
I added a fiddle. Please take a look
http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkq4978r1a4dnSLl9qi?p=preview

Comment: We have no way to just query by prefix. You need to figure out where the query should end. We order things lexigraphically, so if you wanted c*, then you could startAt c and endAt d, and then throw away any that match exactly d.

Comment: As @AndrewLee mentioned, there is no exact {...}.prefix() query in Firebase, but you can accomplish the same thing when using geohashes, which you know to only contain alphanumeric characters, by combining `startAt()`, `endAt()`, and a non-alphanumeric character in your ending query. For example, to search for prefix `abcd`, you can use `{...}.startAt(null, 'abcd').endAt(null, 'abcd~')`, which will capture all geohashes starting with `abcd` and require no filtering on the client. Obviously, any keys sorted lexicographically after `abcd~` would be missing, but that won't impact geohashes.

Comment: Thanks @RobDiMarco that worked. Can you if it exist in the [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/refere) show where to read about this

Comment: @ErikHellberg See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#startAt